# Combine if statement with case when in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table:

```
df_test <-data.frame(player = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                            position = c('G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'),
                            points = c(9, 15, 19, 22, 32),
                            rebounds = c(5, 7, 7, 12, 11))
```

Suppose that I want to add new column named rating. The rule of the new column is the following:

1. Check if the points are more then 10.
2. Only then, do a case_when to check the other variables:
   - When rebounds are >=7, we add "average" to the variable rating
   - When rebounds are >=10, we add "good" to the variable rating
   - Else, NA

To achieve this, I am using the following code:

```
df_test%>% mutate(new=if(points>=20){
    case_when(rebounds>=7~"good",
              rebounds>10~"best")
})
```

However, this is giving me the following error: the condition has length > 1.

How can we combine if and case_when in the same mutate statement, or is there a possibility to write a case_when inside a case_when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more than one condition inside `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df_test <-data.frame(player = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                     position = c('G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'),
                     points = c(9, 15, 19, 22, 32),
                     rebounds = c(5, 7, 7, 12, 11))

df_test %>% 
  mutate(
    rating = case_when(
      points > 10 & rebounds >= 10 ~ "good",
      points > 10 & rebounds >= 7  ~ "average",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )

  player position points rebounds  rating
1      a        G      9        5    <NA>
2      b        F     15        7 average
3      c        F     19        7 average
4      d        G     22       12    good
5      e        G     32       11    good
```

And yes, you also could add another `case_when`

```
df_test %>% 
  mutate(
    rating = case_when(
      points > 10 ~ case_when(
        rebounds >= 10 ~ "good",
        rebounds >= 7  ~ "average"
      ),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

Comment: I know this works, but the question asks specifically about a way to combine the if with case when, or to use two case when. I need the logic mentionned here in another bigger data set. The data set here is just for illustration. In my original data sets, there are already lots of conditions, so I want sth to make it like a tree with an if statement at the beginning without repeating the same condition many times in the case when

Comment: What if you just add `points <= 10 ~ NA_character_,` as the first `case_when()` condition? If it is sequential then the first true statement will go to `NA`, and the other conditions will only come into play afterwards. Shouldn't be any need to nest statements as such - that would be true in the world of SQL that dplyr borrows heavily from for this function.

Comment: I added another option, with 2 `case_when`'s

Comment: @ViníciusFélix is there a way to combine the case_when with an if statement? The question is answered, though I want to learn if there is a way to do this. Thanks